# Ubuntu 20.04 sound problem on system start

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I read lots of articles about ubuntu sound problems .

I also checked this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingGuide .

My problem is when i turn on the system sound is disabled .

when i run this command `alsactl restore` the sound comes back but after a restart i must run this again . 
how can i solve this ?

Maybe as another question look at my sound configurations :

[image]
.

As you can see the `TU116 high definition` is unplugged & unavailable . the other options are also unavailable . why ?

is there a way to make them available ?

here is my sound settings :

[image: Sound Settings]